# Main Office 365 (O365) left navigation pane keeps opening and closing

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

When I'm logged into Microsoft O365 on the main/primary dashboard, the left navigation pane that shows all your applications keeps opening and closing on its own.  What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: So this is about the Office 365 website, right?

Comment: Have a try to change a browser, it seems to be a browser caused issue.

Comment: Sorry.  I haven't been online in a while.  Yes, this happens in Office 365.  The App Launcher on the main screen (the dashboard) opens and closes while I am working in the browser.  I don't click the 9 box shortcut in the upper left corner but if I move my mouse around, the app launcher panel opens and closes randomly.  --- I tried using FireFox and the same issue occurs.